# Add an node to an xml when the same node is present in the xml as an empty tag

Tags: java, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESPONSE>
   <STATUS>
      <SERVERTIME><![CDATA[15319123123262]]></SERVERTIME>
      <TYPE><![CDATA[getData]]></TYPE>
      <RESPONSE_VERSION><![CDATA[1]]></RESPONSE_VERSION>
      <DATA_VERSION><![CDATA[1]]></DATA_VERSION>
      <VALUE><![CDATA[1]]></VALUE>
      <ERRORS />
      <WARNINGS />
   </STATUS>
   <DATA>
      <CONTENT RECORDID="f2e110aa8ca24aewq929d26b9fcf3108962">
         <METARESOURCEPATH><![CDATA[sites/xyz/content/meta/INFORMATION/0/INF427/]]></METARESOURCEPATH>
         <REVIEW_TIMESTAMP><![CDATA[2018-07-20 15:36:00 IST]]></REVIEW_TIMESTAMP>
         <REVIEW_TIMESTAMP_MILLIS><![CDATA[1532081160000]]></REVIEW_TIMESTAMP_MILLIS>
         <VIEWS>
            <VIEW>
               <NAME><![CDATA[xyz]]></NAME>
               <REFERENCE_KEY><![CDATA[xyz]]></REFERENCE_KEY>
               <GUID><![CDATA[6d024478feb441231661f163de62d6e]]></GUID>
               <OBJECTID><![CDATA[001]]></OBJECTID>
               <PARENTID />
               <CHILDCOUNT><![CDATA[8]]></CHILDCOUNT>
            </VIEW>
         </VIEWS>
         <CATEGORIES />
      </CONTENT>
   </DATA>
</RESPONSE>
```

I need to add an element to CATEGORIES WHICH IS OF THE FORMAT.
When ever i try to add a new category it does not accept it because it finds a duplicate categories tag. But when i try to remove that empty tag , that is also not accepted because getelementbyname only returns null for categories.

```
<CATEGORIES>
            <CATEGORY>
               <NAME><![CDATA[xyz]]></NAME>
               <REFERENCE_KEY><![CDATA[xyz]]></REFERENCE_KEY>
               <GUID><![CDATA[6d024478feb441231661f163de62d6e]]></GUID>
               <OBJECTID><![CDATA[001]]></OBJECTID>
               <PARENTID />
               <CHILDCOUNT><![CDATA[8]]></CHILDCOUNT>
            </CATEGORY>
 </CATEGORIES>
```

How can this be done with max efficiency ?

Comment: This is an org.w3c.dom.Document? What do you mean 'WHICH IS OF THE FORMAT'? Can't you just add the category as a new child to the existing categories tag? Your getElementByName for CATEGORIES should succeed, obviously: can you show us the code that you're trying and doesn't work?

Comment: The Category is of the format  <CATEGORIES>
            <CATEGORY>
               <NAME><![CDATA[xyz]]></NAME>
               <REFERENCE_KEY><![CDATA[xyz]]></REFERENCE_KEY>
               <GUID><![CDATA[6d024478feb441231661f163de62d6e]]></GUID>
               <OBJECTID><![CDATA[001]]></OBJECTID>
               <PARENTID />
               <CHILDCOUNT><![CDATA[8]]></CHILDCOUNT>
            </CATEGORY>
 </CATEGORIES>   

and i am trying to append child newCATEGORY which has a category element

finaldocument.getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNextSibling().appendChild(newCATEGORY);

Comment: getElementsByTagName works for me: https://gist.github.com/RupW/f933b97e018624a8ef127c7bc4937442 Note that the NodeList is result lazily-populated so you need to e.g. enumerate it or count the entries before you'll see it populated in the debugger, in case that's your problem?